# How to clean foreverjs logs for running processes?

Tags: node.js, forever

How do I clean logs for foreverjs for a running process? I can manually delete the log files but that results in forever not logging anymore.

I've also seen cleanlogs but that only removes historical logs, but not affecting logs of any active processes.

Comment: `forever cleanlogs`?

Comment: Thanks I saw this but doesn't seem to work for running processes. I've edited my question to be more specific.

Comment: May be some like this help: `for i in /var/forever/path/to/log/*; do cat /dev/null > $i; done`

Comment: Awesome, it works - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Linux, may be some like this help:

`for i in /var/forever/path/to/log/*; do cat /dev/null > $i; done`

Answer (score 13):

From the forever documentation:

```
forever cleanlogs    [CAREFUL] Deletes all historical forever log files
```

Comment: Thanks I saw this but I want to clean log files for long running processes that are still active - cleanlogs doesn't seem to do anything in this situation. I'll edit my answer to be more specific. Not sure why this was downvoted either...

Comment: This doesn't delete the log for the running process

Answer (score 2):

I needed this just now and this was my solution:

```
➜  ~ forever list
info:    Forever processes running
data:        uid  command                                   script                                                                  forever pid  id logfile                 uptime          
data:    [0] n8Hy /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/node app.js --genesis node.json --config config.json 1941    1955    /root/.forever/n8Hy.log 30:16:11:52.822 
➜  ~ echo "deleted..." > /root/.forever/n8Hy.log
```

This will basically overwrite the whole log file with the text "deleted...", of course you can just overwrite it with an empty string.

note that >> will append a line to a file, but > will just delete everything and add a line to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to be followed to clear single log file:

- Go to forever log directory
- cp /dev/null filename.log

Steps to be followed to clear all log file:

- for i in /var/forever/path/to/log/*; do cat /dev/null > $i; **As mentioned by stdob**

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
$ forever list
```

Copy log path.

Using VIM:

Select all and delete (actually move to buffer)

```
:%d
```

Then save file

```
:x
```